# ASP.NET Core: custom cookie processing

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core

I need to have some cookie processing in my app (update session variable on signing-in/out). First, I have some identity config:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //omitted
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(i =>
        {
            i.Lockout = new LockoutOptions()
            {
                DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5
            };
            i.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            i.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        })
        //omitted
    }
```

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie) suggests I added cookie middleware into the pipeline like this:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        //omitted
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnSigningIn = app.ApplicationServices
                        .GetRequiredService<MyService>().DoSomething
            }

        });

        app.UseIdentity();
        //omitted
    }
```

That all doesn't work. `DoSomething` isn't called. If I write a lambda in `ConfigureServices` it works:

```
i.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents    
{
    OnSigningIn = async context => { await Task.FromResult(1); }
};
```

So the question (actually two). How can I request a service in the `ConfigureServices` method OR how make the Events in the `UseCookieAuthentication` work?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as in the event requires a callback (it'll be called later when all the services have been set) and the callback accepts `BasePrincipalContext` through which `HttpContext` can be accessed I can declare a static method in which `HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<Type>()` can be called so that I get a requred service instance